# Jquery nestable plugin item click event not working, I have added button in nestable list and bind a click event on it

Tags: jquery, jquery-nestable

```
<li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
<div class="dd-handle text">
<div class="inline w-200">Data Issued</div><div">Date</div>
<div class="dd-btn"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm" aria-label="edit attribute"><i class="fa fa-pencil text-navy" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
 </div>
 </li>
```

i tried to open a modal on edit button click but button is not clickable in nestable list

Comment: why not `$('.dd-list .dd-item').on('click'`

Comment: I can see alert when I run your code.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i tried to open a modal on edit button click but button is not clickable in nestable list

Comment: finally i got the solution, it's working like a charm :)     // mousedown prevent nestable click
        $('.dd a').on('mousedown', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

Comment: Thanks @Rabia, Works Great.

Comment: Thanks @Rabia, You saved my time

Comment: @Rabia, Please post it as a answer.

Comment: @Rabia Thanks for that!